# What does it mean when someone writes a reunion/intersection symbol before a single set?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I don’t understand why it is a symbol before every set. I know that we can intersect or reunite two sets, A and B, but these examples make me confused.

Comment: Given a function $F:I\to\mathcal{Sets}$, the notation $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} F(i)$ stands for the set $X$ satisfying $$\forall x,\ (x\in X\longleftrightarrow\forall i\in I,\ x\in F(i))$$ and $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} F(i)$ stands for the set $Y$ such that $$\forall x,(x\in Y\longleftrightarrow\exists i\in I,\ x\in F(i))$$

Comment: @Gae. S.  I don't think the OP will understand this

Comment: What does it mean when someone write a $\sum$ symbol before a single number? (e.g. $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac1{2^n}$?

Comment: I don't understand the close vote. This seems a straightforward and legitimate question about notation. Glad to see it has gotten some answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand how **intersection** and **union** work for two sets, you can probably see how that would work for more than two sets, for example:

- the union of three sets $A \cup B \cup C$ (*all elements belonging to at least one of the three sets*)
- the intersection of three sets $A \cap B \cap C$ (*all elements belonging to all three sets*)

If we label them differently, by numbering them, then it becomes easier to do this for an arbitrary number of sets, for example:

- the union of $n$ sets $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_n$
- the intersection of $n$ sets $A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_n$

We abbreviate such expressions in a way similar to symbolic summations and products, that is:

- $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_n$
- $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i = A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_n$

You can then even extend this to an infinite number of sets, again notationally similar to infinite sums or products, to create an infinite union or intersection:

- $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i =\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_n \cup \ldots$
- $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i =\bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_i = A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_n \cap \ldots$

In general you can have $i$ run through any set of indices $I$ and we write: $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} A_i$ and $\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} A_i$.

Answer (score 1):

It means you take an intersection or union of a lot of sets (in this case infinitely many) at once. Let's take the set $B$ in your picture as an example. It says:
$$
B = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left[ -1 + \frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right].
$$
What this means is that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we consider the set $[-1 + \frac{1}{n}, 1 - \frac{1}{n}]$ and then we take the union of all those sets. So:
$$
B = \left[-1 + \frac{1}{1}, 1 - \frac{1}{1} \right] \cup \left[-1 + \frac{1}{2}, 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right] \cup \left[-1 + \frac{1}{3}, 1 - \frac{1}{3} \right] \cup \ldots
$$
Can you determine what this set $B$ is? Can you write the other examples in the above form as well? And in a maybe even simpler form?

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is a union of intervals.  The subscript on the $\bigcup$ tells you there is one interval for each $n \gt 1$.  The interval for $n=2$ is $(-\frac 12,\frac 12)$.  The interval for $n=3$ is $(-\frac 23,\frac 23)$ and so on.  You are then being asked to describe 
$$A=(-\frac 12,\frac 12)\cup(-\frac 23,\frac 23)\cup(-\frac 34,\frac 34)\cup \ldots $$
more simply.